# ImageData returns slightly different RGB values than specified when creating a graphic

Tags: graphics, image-processing

Why does the following not return precisely {0.99,0.5,0.49}?
Is there a way to avoid the discrepancy?

```
In[2089]:= 
ImageData[
  Show[Graphics[{FaceForm[RGBColor[0.99, 1/2, 0.490000]], 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}], ImageSize -> 20, 
   ImagePadding -> None]][[10, 10]]

Out[2089]= {0.988235, 0.501961, 0.490196}
```

Comment: Use `c/255` where `c` is in interval `[0,255]` for values of colors to be exact. Or use hexadecimal `RGBColor["#ff0000"]`.

Comment: Do you want a 20 by 20 image filled with `RGBColor[0.99, 1/2, 0.490000]`? Try `img = Image[ConstantArray[RGBColor[0.99, 1/2, 0.490000], {20, 20}]]` . Verify with `Flatten[ImageData[img], 1] // DeleteDuplicates` is `{{0.99, 0.5, 0.49}}`.

Answer (score 7):

The real numbers (RGB) spanning `[0,1]` have to be put into bytes (Range `0..255` permissible levels).

Don't know the actual algorithm, but assuming that the algorithm `Rescale`s:

```
Rescale[{0.99, 0.5, 0.49}, {0, 1}, {0, 255}] // Round
```

> {252, 128, 125}

which after conversion for display gives:

```
{252, 128, 125}/255 // N
```

> {0.988235, 0.501961, 0.490196}

Comment: Thank you!  This was helpful.  It is somewhat annoying that Mathematica won't accept rgb values in the form of integers in [0,255], but I guess it is easy enough to write a function to do that myself.